# Which word(s) does "nuclear" modify in "by nuclear action or radiation or radioactive contamination"

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions

Is the word *nuclear* assumed after the "or" in the following sentence?

"by nuclear action or radiation or radioactive contamination"

In other words, does the *or* assume that the *nuclear* applies to *radiation* and *radioactive contamination*?

Comment: Without more context, it's unclear. There are other sources of radiation besides nuclear activity. (The whole concept and distinction is unscientific anyway.)

Comment: Whether the three-way zeugma here kicks in right after "by" or only after "by nuclear" is not at all clear from the syntax; but the redundancy of having "nuclear" modify "radioactive contamination" inclines me to the former reading. Good writers tend not to make their readers figure such stuff out, though. Repeating "by" or inserting *(a), (b),* and *(c)* would make the sentence (of which your sample is merely a fragment, BTW) more nearly foolproof for the reader.

Comment: Please post the full sentence; we can't give a good answer without that.

Comment: You could get round the problem by saying '...by nuclear action, or resulting/associated radiation or radioactive contamination'.

Comment: These sort of lists often need to be re-engineered to make their intention obvious. It would be impossible to deduce the true meaning without the advice of the author.

Comment: The very existence of this question is all the proof you need that either reading is possible.

Comment: The quote seems to come from this site: http://www.propertycasualty360.com/2014/06/27/ask-the-fcs-experts-the-nuclear-sun-edition As a physicist, let me mention that while "nuclear action" and "nuclear radiation" make sense, "nuclear radioactive contamination" is not a commonly used expression.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "by nuclear action or radiation or radioactive contamination" can be read in at least three possible ways:

> "by nuclear action or [by] radiation or [by] radioactive contamination"

or

> "by nuclear action or [nuclear] radiation or [by] radioactive contamination"

or

> "by nuclear action or [by] radiation [contamination] or radioactive contamination"

The first interpretation treats the three phrases "nuclear action." "radiation," and "radioactive contamination" as interchangeable options—you could put them in any order, and each of the three would remain an independent option.

The second interpretation treats "nuclear action or radiation" as a nested pair that share the adjective *nuclear*. To move them apart in the sentence, you would have to make the word nuclear an explicit part of the second term, "nuclear radiation"; but at that point the three options would again be independent and interchangeable.

The third interpretation treats "radiation or radioactive contamination" as the nested pair, with *contamination* as their shared element. In this case to make the three terms interchangeable and independent, you'd have to change the second term to explicitly say "radiation contamination."

Less likely is the possibility that the adjective *nuclear* is supposed to attach to each of the three elements in the phrase, or that the noun *contamination* is supposed to apply to all three.

Unfortunately, the author has left every reader to try to figure out which combination the author had in mind. Obviously that's not a problem for readers who know enough about the subject to recognize what the author must have meant. But some readers won't be so lucky, and the author's failure to clarify (through additional punctuation or wording) precisely how he or she wanted readers to understand the phrase is directly responsible for their their difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment does not reveal the answer directly.  There is a clue in the last two items.  "Radiation" and "radioactive contamination" refer two two separate ways an item can indicate "hot" on a meter.  The first occurs if object is exposed to a radioactive source and the second occurs if the object has been "dusted."

They are quite different with regard to decontamination.  From this I assume that the items in the sentence are completely separate and "nuclear" applies only to the first item.